# How do I beat Asgore with very limited healing items?

Tags: undertale

I don't think that I have enough healing items for this battle. I only have instant noodles (one pack), but I can't buy anything else, since I only have 30 gold. How can I beat Asgore?

Answer (score 5):

Asgore is the final(-ish) boss of the neutral/pacifist route. As such, he's got a couple of moves that are difficult to avoid. He's a moderately difficult boss (though nowhere close to some of the others, especially those in the Genocide run), so learning his attacks helps greatly in your survival.

## Combat Tips

The one move that got me the most often was when he slashes the entire screen with either the blue or orange strikes. The key to dodging that attack is to pay attention to his eyes right before the strikes happen - his eyes will flash in a sequence of blue and orange, then the strikes will happen in the same order. For blue strikes, you need to be non-moving to dodge the attack; for orange, you need to be in motion. This is similar to all the other blue/orange motion puzzles in the game.

For one of his attacks, you can see his paws, which will move in an arc summoning fireballs as they go. The fireballs will home in on where your soul was when they started moving. I've found that the best way to dodge this attack is to start on one side of the screen (left or right), then as soon as the paws start moving, travel to the opposite side of the screen. It doesn't work 100% of the time, but I've dodged this pretty well using this strategy.

Most of his other attacks are bullet based, and unfortunately the only advice I can offer here are to learn the patterns and learn how to dodge them.

One good thing is that you can never drop below 1 HP in a single round. So for example, if you take damage during a fireball attack and only have 1 HP left, Asgore will stopp attacking for that phase. This lets you have a chance to heal once your health reaches the critical point.

## Preparation Tips

If you're still having trouble beating Asgore, there are some things you can do to help yourself before the fight.

If eat a butterscotch pie or talk to Asgore during the fight 3 times, his attack and defense power will drop a little bit for the rest of the fight. (Talking to him only works if you have 0 EXP). This makes him take more damage and makes his attack deal less damage.

If you don't have any healing items, you can always go buy more. If you don't have enough money, remember that you can always sell Dog Residue at the Temmie Shop for 2 gp. Dog Residue duplicates itself in your inventory if you try to use it, so it's a slow but infinite source of money. You can also buy Cloudy Glasses (30 gp) from the turtle guy in Waterfall, and sell them at the Temmie Shop for 50 gp.

Finally, if you still can't beat him, you can always buy the Temmie Armor, which drastically reduces incoming damage, increases your attack power, and also increases the period of invincibility after getting hit. To get the armor, you first need to "pay 4 tem's colleg", which costs 1000 gp. After that, the armor becomes available for 9999 gp. Though it looks expensive, don't worry - the price decreases for each time you die in game, up to 25 deaths. If you've died 25 times, the price is a measly 750 gp.

Comment: Asgore will continue his attack phase even if you go down to 1 hp in the same one that yo have 1 HP left.